# Ad mediation in universal Windows app (xaml)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a universal windows app (or WP8.1 XAML and Windows 8.1) with adControl.
In each app, adcontrol is included in a userControl because it's a different use in each platforms.

For the moment everything was working well in my WP8.1 app and in my Windows 8.1 app.

Today, i tried to replace AdControl with Ad Mediation in my Windows Phone app.
I followed this documentation : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn864359.aspx

My WP8.1 app is running with good ads.

**BUT,** ads in Windows 8.1 app are disappeared.

I have no error, "Internet (client)" capability checked, "Microsoft Advertising SDL for Windows 8.1 (XAML)" added to my project references. But no more ads...

Does any one have the same problem after add "ad mediation" ? Is it because Ad Mediation replace some packages somewhere in my project?

Comment: According to MSDN :
If you're adding ad mediation to an app which is already monetizing with any of the ad networks supported by ad mediation, be sure to remove the existing ad implementation and all of its references before proceeding.

Comment: Yes, but i did it in my windows phone project.
I'm supposed to keep AdControl in my Windows 8.1 project so i didn't remove existing implementation.
Maybe i have to remove everything and add it again to my Windows app.

Comment: I tried to remove Microsoft Advertising SDk for Windows 8.1 and to add it again. But no more ads to display .

Comment: i know its a little too late to answer but ad mediation does not support windows 8 store apps...so you should just continue to use individual ad sdk's in windows store version of the app..however Microsoft does plan to  support ad mediation for store apps in future

Comment: forgot to mention, you can try AdrotatorV2 https://github.com/Adrotator/AdrotatorV2

Answer (score 0):

I don't have THE answer but you can do these tests :

- **Display Ad with test values (test values are defined by microsoft to test ads) :**

You can find test values in this page :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/advertising-windows-test-mode-values(v=msads.10).aspx

Choose ad with same size that yours.

If ad is not displayed, maybe your appId or adId is wrong.

If ad is displayed, it's a good thing, your implementation is well done.

- **Try to modify AdControl size**

If you try to display ad with 728x90 size but your adControl has a 364x45, try to modify adControl size and set 728x90 size.

If ad is displayed, it's because adControl size is wrong. You have to modify it and to set it with same size than ad size.

--

In my case, i had a adControl with 364x45 size and i was displaying ad inside with 728x90 size.

Before inserting Ad Mediation, everything was working good, and my ad was maybe truncated but was displayed.

Then I installed Ad mediation (in WP project). I had to set same size between ad Control and ad (in Windows project).

i can't explain why, but i think that Ad mediation has updated Microsoft Advertising SDK when i installed it, and in this new SDK version, ad is only displayed if AdControl has the same size.
if someone has another idea, please feel free to give me it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the AdMediator.config contains correct values. Then check if the adunit id is same in the implementation, config and the dev center.

I create the ad mediation control as follows:

```
var adunit = new Microsoft.AdMediator.WindowsPhone8.AdMediatorControl
{
    Name = "AdMediator_XXXXXX",
    Id = "AdMediator-Id-XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    Width = 480,
    Height = 80,
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
    Visibility = App.SettingsViewModel.IsTrial ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed
};
```

PS Although MSDN says that you have to remove other ad implementations, I currently have kept Microsoft advertising in my app and it continues to serve ads after its published.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that for windows 10...there's only one ad size, which is 300x250. In order to see the ad size you created, you need to go to pub center (dev center does not display any ad size information). Yes, microsoft made this process very confusing and stupid.

Because 300xx250 is the only ad size for windows 10, you need specify the admediator control to width=300 and height=250 for it to display ads.

Comment: The original issue was for Windows 8.1. But maybe there is the same problem with Windows 10.

Comment: yup, it is. I started with Windows Phone 8.1 and had the same problem, where the ad size needs to be specified. Back then, it was  easier as only pubcenter manage the ads. Now, you have you use windows dev dashboard to configure the ads and pubcenter to get the ad size.